# How to verify app which is currently using localhost

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have NodeJS app which needs access to Google drive so I added sensitive scope of .../auth/drive, which needs verification by Google even when only running on localhost.

is there an easy way? either skip verification or verify in much simpler way, do hope Google can make my life easy! already took hours if not days to make signin working, now drive, what else ahead!

Comment: Do you want to publish this app for production? Or testing it yourself? If you just want to test it, you can avoid verification by Google (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69343557). If you want to publish it, it has to go through verification. In any case, please consider providing more details in order to better understand your situation.

Comment: thanks Iamblichus, I just want to test it, at least for now, this app is for file transfer from/to google drive, i followed the exact steps as outlined in your link: external, testing not production, added myself as tester, but after running my app, still got 500 error.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: that app (transfer to/from Google drive) works OK now, but another one (view from Google drive) not yet working, the only difference is that the one works is using https while the one doesn't work is using http, perhaps that's the reason? or something wrong w/ my code, let me check again, thanks and very appreciated for your help Iamblichus!

Comment: Please consider providing the relevant parts of your code, it's hard to know what's going on otherwise.

Comment: turned out that app verification is OK, only code is wrong, thanks Iamblichus for your link, now I have to crack another issue, I'll post as separate question if I cannot solve it, it's about (access) token.

Comment: Consider providing an answer to this question, if you got to solve the original issue.

Comment: thanks Iamblichus, in fact, the link you provided (stackoverflow.com/a/69343557) is the answer, I don't know how to make your comment as solution except vote, should I answer my own question w/ that link?

Comment: Hi, I voted to close this question as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/69343557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as pointed by Iamblichus, stackoverflow.com/a/69343557 is the solution

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).